# How do I compare with css class in ng-click?

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to prevent ng-click action if css class is empty or not equal until class="visited" that allows ng-click action

Here is my code

```
<ul class="nav nav-wizard">
    <li>
        <a href="#step1" ng-click="step=1">Step 1</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#step2" ng-click="step=2">Step 2</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#step3" ng-click="step=3">Step 3</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#step4" ng-click="step=4">Step 4</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#step5" ng-click="step=5">Step 5</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

These shouldn't be executed by click until css class is showed like this.

```
<li class="visited">
    <a href="#step1" ng-click="step=1">Step 1</a>
</li>
```

This is able to do click if it meets class="visited" condition.

Comment: I think that you should store when a link is visited instead of rely of the value of the css attribute.

Answer (score 1):

```
<a ng-click="doSomething($event.currentTarget.getAttribute('class'))">Hello, click  me</a>

// In controller:
$scope.doSomething = function(classes) {
    if(classes && classes.indexOf("visited") > -1){
         //do click properly
    }else{
       //do nothing
    }
};
```

https://jsfiddle.net/rpuczu4a/

This is probably something you **don't want to do** as AngularJS philosophy is to focus on model manipulation and let AngularJS do the rendering (based on hints from the declarative UI). Manipulating DOM elements and attributes from a controller is a big no-no in AngularJS world.

Comment: I'm saying stop trying to control flow execution based on a CSS value. The conditions should be evaluated in the model from the controller. You wouldn´t need to access directly to ui elements.

Comment: It doesn't matter, sometimes we have to break the rules to get excepted result.

In that case, these links can automatically generated class="visited" I really want to make them conditional click.

Comment: You've got a point there, but I think that you can change to follow proper angularJS  conventions.

Comment: Please explain properly that you would answer my question.

Comment: I've included a jsfiddle

Comment: Thanks but there a minor problem, Im not sure if you did read my question it says that we really need to solve like this

<li class=visited><a></a></li>


In that case you did <a class="visited"></a>


If you fix with <li> I will mark your answer as accepted, sorry for being prick!

Comment: Actually, we have a problem, your answer DOESN'T solve my question due to count of steps, 

basically number of steps like step=1, step=2, step=3

Answer (score 0):

You can make it work like so using the pointer-events css attribute (The jQuery is just demonstration Javascript):

```js
$('a[ng-click]').click(function(event) { event.preventDefault(); this.innerHTML = "YAY"; });
```

```css
a[ng-click] {
  pointer-events:none;
}

a[ng-click].visited {
  pointer-events:all;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a href="#test" ng-click="test">Test(DISALLOW CLICK)</a> <br />
<a href="#test2" ng-click="test2" class="visited">Test (ALLOW CLICK)</a>
```

Comment: Notice if you see <a class ="visited"></a> instead of <li class="visited"><a></a></li> anyway I made jsFiddle how to accomplish to do not use class="" inside of <a> it needs to be with <li> 

http://jsfiddle.net/qzuqo8k9/